# Update multiple DIV's from one JSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have searched a lot but as I have limited skills in javascript I have decided to ask for assistance
I have created a json format output generated by an ASP page on another webserver that looks like this:

```
    {"id": "K97", "name": "Activity level", "room": "Appartment", "floor": "Main",     "dimmable": false, "status": 17, "string": Activity level: 0, "value": 0, "since": "07-01-2014 06:51:55", "type": "Status Only", "status_support": false, "misc": "16"}, {"id": "V3", "name": "Day or Night", "room": "Appartment", "floor": "Main", "dimmable": false, "status": 3, "string": Day, "value": 2, "since": "07-01-2014 05:59:31", "type": "Virtual device", "status_support": false, "misc": "768"} ……. {"id": "R96", "name": "Radiator status HS", "room": "Appartment", "floor": "Secondary", "dimmable": false, "status": 17, "string": Bathroom;22;Bedroom;22;Dining room;22;Living room;22;, "value": 0, "since": "00:00:00", "type": "Virtual", "status_support": false, "misc": "0"}
```

The structure will be static but the amount will vary from time to time.
What I would like, is to define a div id from each of the items in a format like this – say, split the json data into multiple DIV’s:

```
DIV id=id-K97-status,
DIV id=id-K97-string,
DIV id=id-V3-status,
```

….

and that the values of the DIV id’s will be refreshed every 1 second or even better when any value changes.

I have a script that can refresh one id at the time, but it will then call the back end webserver too often.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be help you

```
function getFormattedHTML(data)
{
 var statusDiv, stringDiv;
 if(data.status){
  stausDiv=$('<div id=id-"+data.id+"-status/>');
 }
 //etc
}
```